# How to handle this encoding error in Python 3.6 which is fine in Python 2.6?

Tags: python, file

HI I am wondering why the following code works in Python 2.6 but not in Python 3.6.

```
f = open('test', 'w')
f.write(chr(144)) # this is an uppercase E with an accent
f.close()
```

Comment: `chr(144)` is not an E with an accent, that would be `chr(200)` or `chr(201)` most likely (it depends on exactly what kind of accent you expect). Character 144 (`0x90`) is a control character in all the extended-ASCII encodings, so it's unlikely you can fix this easily.

Comment: @Blckknght Well, http://www.asciitable.com/ says it's É. So I guess it's not a control character in **all** extensions... (not that I trust that stupid site, but still...)

Comment: That's Code page 437 used in the first IBM pcs. It's outdated by several decades. Don't use that reference.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I should have been more specific. In all the ISO 8859 encodings, it's a control character (part of the "C1" block).

Answer (score 4):

You just need to specify an encoding:

```
f = open('test', 'w', encoding="ansi")
```

---

Since `ansi` is available for Windows only it is better to use another encoding ([Håken Lid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1977847/h%c3%a5ken-lid) suggested utf-8 see comments below)

Comment: @anupamb  No problem.  Happy to help. :-)

Comment: Note that the 'ansi' encoding is some weird old encoding which is only available on the windows platform. If you have a choice, you should prefer to use utf-8 everywhere instead.

Comment: @HåkenLid  I will mention that in my post.  I have only just found that out.  I do run Windows.

Answer (score 1):

By using `encoding='ansi'` as in

```
f = open('test', 'w', encoding = 'ansi')
```

Comment: I deleted my previous answer because it did not work for me.  Just trying to find out where I went wrong.

Comment: @Simon I'd say the main problem is that `chr(144)` doesn't actually produce "uppercase E with an accent" but the "[DEVICE CONTROL STRING](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0090/index.htm)" character (whatever that means).

Comment: Interesting.  As @StefanPochmann it is indeed that.  I will continue to try and solve the problem so that it works for me.

Comment: @anupamb If it does "work" for you then I'd say you must've made a second mistake that cancels your first.

Comment: @Stefan This is my code on Windows: with open('test', 'r', encoding = 'ansi') as f: print(f.read())

Answer (score 1):

Python 3 by default opens files and writes text using the system encoding. Since python 3 strings are unicode, `chr(144)` is a control character, and not `É`. If you want to write the byte value 144 to your file, you can open it in byte mode.

This should give the same result as your python 2 code.

```
with open('test', 'wb') as fp:
    fp.write(bytes([144]))
```

Or you can simply use the correct character in the string. If you want to use some weird archaic encoding where `É` is 144, you can do that as well, by passing an encoding argument to `open()`.

```
with open('test', 'w', encoding='cp437') as fp:
    fp.write('É')
```

Comment: Hmm, better, but for example on my PC it's cp1252 and I don't think that's a unicode encoding.

Comment: Python uses `local.getpreferedencoding(False)` to determine which encoding to use. The most sensible would be utf-8, but it might be possible to set it to some non-unicode encoding. I assume modern versions of windows would use utf-8 or utf-16. But I don't know.

Comment: It's 2018, and this ought to work across all platforms:  `open('poop.txt', 'w').write('')`

Comment: I'm using the latest Windows (released 7 days ago). And your poop code gives me a UnicodeEncodeError. Really cp1252 is just a *character* encoding.